# using lapply or purrr::map where results from first list element is used for later list element

Tags: r, lapply, purrr

Assuming the following list:

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = 1:3,
                  x = 1:3,
                  y = 4:6,
                  level = rep("L1", 3))

df2 <- data.frame(id = 4:6,
                  x = 2:4,
                  y = 5:7,
                  level = rep("L1", 3))

df3 <- data.frame(id = 1:6,
                  x = 1:6,
                  y = 7:13,
                  level = rep("L2", 6))

my_list <- list(df1, df2, df3)
```

I now want to first "loop" through the data frames that have level `L1` and in this example here simply take the sum of x + y (rowwise).

However, when I reach df3 (which has level = `L2`), I want to first row bind the respective sum results from df1 and df2, match this result to df3 (based on the id column) and then for df3 / level = `L2` take the sum of x + y + the result from the L1 levels.

I could hard code this if it were just two levels, however, I potentially have a lot of levels.

So my problem is: how do I write the function or get lapply/purrr::map to kind of chunk the code so that it does something for L1, then takes these results and feed that into the next chunk for L2, and once we are through L2, we'd go to L3 and so on.

The expected results after running sth. like `lapply(my_list, custom_function)` would be

```
result1 <- data.frame(id = 1:3,
                      x = 1:3,
                      y = 4:6,
                      level = rep("L1", 3),
                      result = c(5, 7, 9))

result2 <- data.frame(id = 4:6,
                      x = 2:4,
                      y = 5:7,
                      level = rep("L1", 3),
                      result = c(7, 9, 11))

result3 <- data.frame(id = 1:6,
                      x = 1:6,
                      y = 7:12,
                      level = rep("L2", 6),
                      result_L1 = c(5, 7, 9, 7, 9, 11),
                      result = c(13, 17, 21, 21, 25, 29))

final_result <- list(result1, result2, result3)
```

(explaining the calc a bit:

- df1, first row: x + y is 1 + 4, so result = 5.
- ...
- when we get to df3 which has level L2, we'd first match this result (5) to df3, then take the sum of x + y + result_L1 = 1 + 7 + 5 = 13.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The complex operation happens between levels, so I would first reorganize to
a structure where you have a list with one data frame per level. Since `x + y`
needs to always be calculated, we can also do that along the way:

```r
library(tidyverse)

lvls <- bind_rows(my_list) %>%
  mutate(result = x + y) %>%
  split(.$level)

lvls
#> $L1
#>   id x y level result
#> 1  1 1 4    L1      5
#> 2  2 2 5    L1      7
#> 3  3 3 6    L1      9
#> 4  4 2 5    L1      7
#> 5  5 3 6    L1      9
#> 6  6 4 7    L1     11
#> 
#> $L2
#>    id x  y level result
#> 7   1 1  7    L2      8
#> 8   2 2  8    L2     10
#> 9   3 3  9    L2     12
#> 10  4 4 10    L2     14
#> 11  5 5 11    L2     16
#> 12  6 6 12    L2     18
```

To add the results of the previous level, we can then use `accumulate()`:

```r
lvls %>%
  accumulate(function(l1, l2) {
    l1 %>%
      select(id, result0 = result) %>%
      right_join(l2, by = "id") %>%
      mutate(result = result + result0)
  })
#> $L1
#>   id x y level result
#> 1  1 1 4    L1      5
#> 2  2 2 5    L1      7
#> 3  3 3 6    L1      9
#> 4  4 2 5    L1      7
#> 5  5 3 6    L1      9
#> 6  6 4 7    L1     11
#> 
#> $L2
#>   id result0 x  y level result
#> 1  1       5 1  7    L2     13
#> 2  2       7 2  8    L2     17
#> 3  3       9 3  9    L2     21
#> 4  4       7 4 10    L2     21
#> 5  5       9 5 11    L2     25
#> 6  6      11 6 12    L2     29
```

---

Based on the extra context in your comments, I would take a bit of a
different approach. The idea is still to accumulate weights across levels,
but I’d push the other logic into a helper function to handle each level:

```r
find_weights <- function(data, balance, stratify = character(), weights = "wt") {
  if (length(stratify) > 0) {
    # Apply separately to strata
    strata <- data[stratify]
    
    data <- split(data, strata) |>
      lapply(find_weights, balance, weights = weights) |>
      unsplit(strata)
    
    return(data)
  } 
  
  # Get initial weights
  w0 <- data[[weights]]
  if (is.null(w0)) {
    w0 <- rep_len(1, nrow(data))
  }
  
  # Find balancing weights (use your function)
  f <- factor(data[[balance]])
  n <- as.numeric(tapply(w0, f, sum))
  w <- prop.table(1 / n[f]) * sum(w0)
  
  # Update weights
  data[[weights]] <- w0 * w
  
  data
}
```

Some example data:

```r
data <- data.frame(country = rep(c("A", "B"), c(3, 5)), sex = c("m", "f"))
data
#>   country sex
#> 1       A   m
#> 2       A   f
#> 3       A   m
#> 4       B   f
#> 5       B   m
#> 6       B   f
#> 7       B   m
#> 8       B   f
```

And level descriptions:

```r
opts <- list(
  l1 = list(balance = "sex", stratify = "country"),
  l2 = list(balance = "country")
)
```

Then apply, accumulating weights:

```r
Reduce(function(data, opts) {
  find_weights(data, opts$balance, opts$stratify)
}, opts, data, accumulate = TRUE)
#> [[1]]
#>   country sex
#> 1       A   m
#> 2       A   f
#> 3       A   m
#> 4       B   f
#> 5       B   m
#> 6       B   f
#> 7       B   m
#> 8       B   f
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   country sex        wt
#> 1       A   m 0.7500000
#> 2       A   f 1.5000000
#> 3       A   m 0.7500000
#> 4       B   f 0.8333333
#> 5       B   m 1.2500000
#> 6       B   f 0.8333333
#> 7       B   m 1.2500000
#> 8       B   f 0.8333333
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>   country sex        wt
#> 1       A   m 1.0000000
#> 2       A   f 2.0000000
#> 3       A   m 1.0000000
#> 4       B   f 0.6666667
#> 5       B   m 1.0000000
#> 6       B   f 0.6666667
#> 7       B   m 1.0000000
#> 8       B   f 0.6666667
```

Comment: You could also rework this to a grouped `cumsum()`, but using `accumulate()` demonstrates the general strategy for doing calculations that depend on previous results.

Comment: Thanks. I think I overly simplified my use case with using the simple x+y sum as an example. What I would do in real life is: I have several L1 "entities" that I want to calculate weights for, which I'm using `anesrake::anesrake()` for. Once all L1 levels have their weight I need to row-bind these weights and feed them into the next level L2 where I also want to use `anesrake::anesrake()`, but now the previously calculated weights would be passed as an additional argument `weightvec` to the function. Once all L2 entities are weighted that way, I would do the same for L3, L4... and so on.

Comment: @deschen Aha, okay. I think the general principle still is to create a list with each element representing a whole level, and then use `accumulate()` to pass the weights calculated at each level up to the next one. You might need a `.init` with a set of dummy weights for L1. I don't really understand the multiple "entities" aspect here, so that's what I can offer for now. If you're still stuck, perhaps you could ask a new question with a more representative example.

Comment: Yes, definitely will do (or update the question). And my hope as well is that the accumulate idea would still work. As for the multiple entities, let me give an example. In survey research you often apply case weights to account for certain sample imbalancing (e.g. you want to have 50% male/female, but got 40%/60%). Now, let's assume I have done a survey in 5 countries and I want to apply this to each country separately. So I'd have 5 L1 levels (one for each country) where I create the case weights...

Comment: Now, if I now also want to make sure that all my countries get the same weight in my study (this would be L2 level), I need to also create case weights for each country. However, in order to so so, I first need to apply the L1 weights to each country (or in ther terms weight my data by L1 weight) and then run the weighting function again on L2. Hope this somehow makes sense.

Comment: I see. So at each level you actually have the same underlying data, but 1) a set of initial weights, 2) a factor to balance (e.g. L1 = sex, L2 = country), and (optionally) 3) another factor to stratify by (L1 = country, L2 = NA). And as output you get a new set of weights. Is that right?

Comment: Yes. And the final output would have the weights from all levels, which is: the inital L1 weight (say from sex), L2 weight will be country (derived through first weighting my data by sex separately for each country) and so on.

Comment: I edited in how I'd approach that situation.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I‘ll try to look at it over the weekend.

Comment: I accepted the answer since it does work for the example here. I have to admit, though, that I ended up using a simple for loop where I store the result of each run in a list and then at certain iteration points I just aggregated the stored results and fed them into the function. Reason is that I'm struggling in fully understanding what your approach does so that I can easily adjust it to my real life use case (which is not your fault, don't get me wrong!).